# Undefined reference with xtensa-lx106-elf-gcc?

Tags: c++, c, esp8266, arduino-ide, arduino-esp8266

I'm using Arduino IDE and planning on later moving to a VSCode/Makefile solution.

I have a project that compiles and runs fine if all the code belongs in the main sketch. Once I separate the code, the linkage step fails.

I've boiled it down to a simple demonstration:

### What works

#### Sketch file

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
void methodCall();
#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:

}

void loop() {
 methodCall();
}

void methodCall() {
  random(0,1);
 }
```

### What fails

#### Sketch file

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
void methodCall();
#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:

}

void loop() {
 methodCall();
}
```

#### Methods.c file added to the Arduino IDE sketch via Sketch>'Add File'

```
void methodCall() {
  random(0,1);
 }
```

### Platform.txt modification?

Some questions suggest adding `-lstd++` to the `compiler.c.elf.libs` line in the ESP8266 folder's *platform.txt* file, but it doesn't seem to yield any result for me, and besides the earlier `build.stdcpp_lib=-lstdc++` line seems to take care of that.

### Note about headers

The errors are identical if the method declaration is externalized in a header file `#include`d by the source files. The `random` function is declared in the esp8266/Arduino.h and defined [here](https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/blob/342c4ae6fb847bfc787f80b89a2bb888d942dc32/cores/esp8266/WMath.cpp#L40).

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Arduino's Github

According to https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/issues/1283, where Links2004 states:

> random is a API function from Arduino
> not working on C

the answer seems to be to replace calls to replace calls to `random` to calls to `rand`. Testing demonstrates that both in that demonstration source and the real source, replacing `random()` and `randomSeed` with `rand` and `srand`-based modifications compiles and runs correctly.

### Fixed?

If someone has a better option that allows the use of the C++ `random` function from the C code, I'll gladly replace my "solution" with theirs. *It frustrates me that C code disguised by Arduino as C++ compiles, but the same source cut into several files doesn't, and requires the source itself call different functions.*